# Is $(-3)^n + 5^n$ monotone?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I establish if this sequence is monotone?

If it isn't, is it permanently monotone from a certain n* to infinite?

Comment: Is $n$ intended to be a positive integer?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that

Comment: There have been down votes on two viable approaches to this problem (including mine). It is Ok not to like an approach, but that does not make it wrong. In my experience it is useful to have a wide repertoire of approaches when tackling problems. In particular the two down voted answers here are ones which do not involve dividing by $4$ - this factor of $4$ appears as a special feature of this particular problem. Of course taking advantage of special features is part of a problem-solver's art - but it is also useful to know how to proceed when the tricks run out.

Comment: @MarkBennet The criteria for a down vote is "*This answer is not useful*". A reply does not have to be wrong to be down voted. As mentioned below, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Mark Bennet I usually only down vote *wrong* answers, and I've not down voted anything in this thread.

Comment: @FlybyNight, I'd dare to say that a "This answer is not useful" is a very restricted category: either the answer refer to something else away from the OP's intention or it is **so** wrong that nothing can be profited from it, since *even* wrong answers offer some use many, many times. Anyway, in both cases downvoted there is no explanation, argument or anything. I've already raised this in other parts as I don't think such a downvoting is useful in anyway, yet it many times is annoying. I think people downvoting **should** give a little explanation why they did so, even forced by the system.

Comment: The only reason people make so much fuss about downvotes is because they think they mean more than what their effect produces. If the mathematics is sound, you shouldn't care about anything else. Teaching and learning math is what is important here. Do the downvotes make the answers less correct? Mathematics doesn't have anything to do with democracy. What is the only effect? The more advanced/distant for the OP/perhaps less useful for the OP answers, are placed latter than the simpler/direct/perhaps more useful ones for the OP. Yes, I did downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that a sequence is stictly increasing, we must show that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ for all $n$.
\begin{array}
1(-3)^{n+1}+5^{n+1} &>& (-3)^n + 5^n \\
5^{n+1} - 5^n &>& (-3)^n - (-3)^{n+1} \\
5^n (5-1) &>& (-3)^n (1+3) \\
5^n &>& (-3)^n
\end{array}
When $n$ is even then we have $5^n > 3^n$ which is clearly true. When $n$ is odd we have $5^n > -3^n$ which is clearly true since $5^n$ is positive and $-3^n$ is negative. Hence your sequence increases for all $n\ge 1.$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose
$$(-3)^{n+1} + 5^{n+1} < (-3)^n + 5^n.$$
Then $4\cdot 5^n<4\cdot (-3)^n$. Hence $5^n<(-3)^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: Note this assumes that $n$ is non-negative. For negative $n$ the $(-3)^n$ term, which alternates in sign, becomes dominant.

Comment: +1 Thanks! But I think it is more simple logic to say that "the term n+1 is greater than the term n for each n", instead of saying "it is always false that the term n+1 is smaller than the term n".

Comment: @Mark Bennet: Of course, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=(-3)^n+5^n$. Then we have $a_n=2a_{n-1}+15a_{n-2}$. So as soon as you have two successive positive terms, it is easy to prove that the sequence is increasing.

Here we use that if $a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ then $a_n=(\alpha+\beta)a_{n-1}-\alpha\beta a_{n-2}$ which comes from the general theory of recurrence relations.

Comment: I would like to know why this has been down voted since this is clearly a method which works, and is very different from the other methods proposed. $a_0=2, a_1=2$ and if $a_{n-1},a_{n-2}\gt 0$ we easily have $a_n\gt 2a_{n-1}$.

Comment: I didn't down vote this reply, but I'm afraid to say that I can see how someone might not have thought it were a useful reply. You make several claims which you do not explain and then mention the general theory of recurrence relations. Given the content of the question, it is reasonable to assume the OP would have little or no idea about what you're saying.

Comment: @FlybyNight All you need to do to verify the recurrence is to plug in $a_n$ and see that it works. To prove it, note that $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of $x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$ and hence of $Cx^n-C(\alpha+\beta)x^{n-1}+C\alpha\beta x^{n-2}=0$ (multiply by $Cx^{n-2}$). Then use $C=A, x=\alpha$ and $C=B, x=\beta$ and add. This gives $(A\alpha^n+B\beta^n)-(\alpha+\beta)(A \alpha^{n-1}+B\beta^{n-1})+\alpha\beta(A \alpha^{n-2}+B\beta^{n-2})=0$ or $a_n-(\alpha+\beta)a_{n-1}+\alpha\beta a_{n-2}=0$ - looking up recurrence relations will give the general theory of such things.

Comment: Perhaps if this explanation were included then the answer would be more useful. Having said that, I still think that this is at completely the wrong level for the OP and, as such, is of little use to him. If the OP is unsure how to manipulate inequalities then how do you think he would find a book of the general theory of recurrence relations? I appreciate that you find this method simple, but almost all mathematics is simple to someone somewhere.

Comment: @FlybyNight There is plenty on this site and on the internet generally. And given that similar questions to this one may be marked as duplicates, and that people looking to solve similar questions might look at this one, it's worth having a note of an alternative method. But if someone does not understand an answer the natural thing is to make a comment asking for clarification. I put the answer because I thought it was elementary and probably unusual. Any times you have sums of powers like this, recurrence relations may help. Like vieta's relations and symmetric functions.

Comment: I beg to difer with you, @FlybyNight. No where in the site, its rules or even, I think, its spirit or intention, is there any hint about explaining *everything* in an answer. In fact, many people here (most of them...?) think that an answer by means of hints, half explanations, etc. is way more benefitial for the asker and for anyone else seriously interested in **working** on the question. Giving all, or almost all, is not educating or "helping" but merely doing somebody else's work for him. Furthermore, the OP can *always* ask for some more explanation about some particular point...

Comment: @DonAntonio I didn't say that there was anything on this site. I was just applying my understanding of the word *useful*. IMHO for an answer to be useful it needs to be of use to the person asking the question. I'm entitled to an opinion, am I not?

Comment: You and I both, @FlybyNight...right?

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$$\frac{(-3)^{n+1}+5^{n+1}}{(-3)^n+5^n}=\frac{5^{n+1}\left(\left(-\frac35\right)^{n+1}+1\right)}{5^n\left(\left(-\frac35\right)^n+1\right)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}5>1$$

Comment: Apparently someone didn't like my hint...oh,well.

Comment: See my comment on the question ...